# return in while loop

Tags: c#, mysql, methods, while-loop

I have a method in c# with a database. Now I try to return the value but because the string is created in the `while` loop it says that it doesn't exist. Is there a way that the string `kampioen` with its value created in the while read loop can be returned?

```
public string getkampioen(string selecteditem)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = ("select * FROM clubs where naam = '" + selecteditem + "'");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
           string kampioen = (string)Reader["aantalkampioenschappen"].ToString();
        }
        return kampioen; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the declaration of the variable outside the scope of the while

Comment: With your code as written, if your result set returns `n` records, you're reading all `n` values but discarding the first `n - 1`. Are you sure that's what you want? Depending on exactly what you expect these data sets to look like, perhaps the best approach doesn't use a loop at all.

Comment: Why read multiple records if you only want to return the last one?  Why not just fetch the one record you want in the first place?  Also, be aware that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should be using query parameters and treating input as a value rather than as executable code.

Comment: Also, I think it's worth pointing out that (1) you don't need `select *` since you're only interested in the value of one field—`select aantalkampioenschappen` would suffice—and (2) you should use a parameter instead of writing the value of `selectedItem` directly into the query. Your existing code is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the string before the while loop.

```
public string getkampioen(string selecteditem)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = ("select * FROM clubs where naam = '" + selecteditem + "'");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string kampioen = "";
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
           kampioen = (string)Reader["aantalkampioenschappen"].ToString();
        }
        return kampioen; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the declaration outside the loop:

```
public string getkampioen(string selecteditem)
{
    string kampioen; //declare here
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = ("select * FROM clubs where naam = '" + selecteditem + "'");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
           kampioen = (string)Reader["aantalkampioenschappen"].ToString();
        }
        return kampioen; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, move `kampioen` outside of the loop. But also, if you're looking to get a specific value and not a random one (if there are multiple records returned), you may want to concatenate the string or limit the results to the first row, like so:

```
public string getkampioen(string selecteditem)
{
    string kampioen = string.empty; // declared outside of the while 
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = ("select * FROM clubs where naam = '" + selecteditem + "' limit one");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
           kampioen = (string)Reader["aantalkampioenschappen"].ToString();
        }
        return kampioen; 
    }
}
```